# Referring to specific table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i'm learning bigquery currently and encountered to a problem while training on some of their public datasets.

```
SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.languages]  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(language)
```

I'm trying to separate their language data but i keep getting the error

> Table name "language" cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing.

How exactly do you refer to specific table in BigQuery?

Comment: Array column language is not available . Can you check DDL to verify whether Language column it is present or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using legacy SQL, but you are also using UNNEST, which is specific to standard SQL. Try this instead:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.languages`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(language)
```

While you work on developing the query that you want to run, it would be a good idea to try running it over one of the sample GitHub tables instead of the real one in order to reduce your costs.

Answer (score 2):

You're running the query using the old `legacy SQL` dialect. The clear indication that you're using the legacy format is referring to a table in this format:

```
[project-name:dataset-name.table-name]
```

You need to use the new `standard SQL` dialect to run your query since it's using the `unnest` command. To convert a legacy query to a standard one add `#standardSQL` to the first line of your query and use this format to refer to a table:

```
`project-name.dataset-name.table-name`
```

So in your case, the query would become:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.languages` 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(language)
```